# How do I parse JSON from a twitter search response

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-feed

I am trying to write an application that display tweets in a geographic location on Android device using Android Java SDK.

My question is how do I create the search query in twitter.

Secondly once I have created the query how to I parse the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Java client library like [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/). JTwitter has a `search()` method you can call to conduct the search, and it does all the parsing for you. There are other client libraries as well (e.g., Twitter4J) if you don't like JTwitter for some reason.